# How to map from one table to django model?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working with some "legacy" code and dealing with one problem. I've some mysql schema where are two tables (this is simplified much more stuff goes in here) :

```
article
+------+-------------+-------+------+
| id   | author      | title | year |
+------+-------------+-------+------+
|    1 | author_name | title | 1999 |
+------+-------------+-------+------+

article_pages
+------+------------+----------+
| id   | pages_from | pages_to |
+------+------------+----------+
|    1 |         10 |       15 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

The django model for article and article_pages, looks pretty obvious:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class ArticlePages(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    page_from = models.IntegerField()
    page_to = models.IntegerField()
```

And now in my `views` I need to sort the articels by pages:

`articles = Article.objects.filter(name=current_name_to_filter).order_by('page_from')`

I know that there needs to be `OneToOneFiled` relation between `Article` and `ArticlePages` but I'm not quite sure how to implement that.

I was trying: `pages_from = OneToOneField(ArticlePages.page_from, related_name = 'id')`. I know python pretty well but I'm new to Django. That approach seems to me pretty obvious but it doesn't work. I know that there needs to be some database changes, but calling `python manange.py syncdb` gives no effect. 
The `id` column in both tables is the identifier between them. `id` in `article` and `article_pages` corresponds together.

I need to use: `mysql`, `djangon=1.5.2`

Comment: Did you use [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) to create these models?

Comment: Also in addition to answers. ```Django south```(http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a good tool to manage database changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to point to model, as [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) is ForeignKey with `unique=True` constraint. But you are trying to point to exact id (which is integer). But this is not how thinks work in SQL (and of course in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)).

What is needed:

1. Remove explicitly defined `id` field. Your models all have [primary key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/) integer field with name 'id'. Exactly such field will be created [automatically by django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), if no other primary key field defined.
2. When using `OneToOneField`, point to model class, that you are referencing.

Final result:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class ArticlePages(models.Model):
    page_from = models.OneToOneField(Article)
    page_to = models.OneToOneField(Article)
```

Comment: hmm... do you mean that I need to redefine mysql, and models? I'm not sure if I do some kind of `id` manipulation something else wouldn’t be broken.

Comment: do not modify tables in mysql, update only django models

Comment: Still don't get how it might work... I've made changes you've suggested but still `syncbd` gives nothing. When I get to the shell it raises `DatabaseError`.
I wonder how in your approach `views` object will "know" that `Article` could be ordered by pages that are stored in `ArticlePages` table.

Comment: As it written in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#syncdb), syncdb will not do anything, if you database already has corresponding to model tables. Provide details of your `DatabaseError`, traceback for example.

Answer (score 0):

According to the data tables you showed, it is not clear what is the column that identifies the relation between those two tables. If that is the real case, I could only guess that the `id` column is the one (tables `article` and `article_pages` share the same id which would mean that article with specific `id` corresponds to the row in article_pages with the same `id`).

This should not be the case with Django ORM (at least, I'm not aware that this kind of database structure is possible there). If you are stuck with that database structure, try running the SQL query directly (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

Please, check the tables structure, and update the question if there is something more. Maybe some articles' container table (like book/publication).

Comment: I made the update `id` is the identifier here. And yes the structure is a bit different, but the idea is like this. I wanted to explain problem as easy as it's possible.

Comment: I have never tried the following, but if you have time, please try and send out the results:

Comment: (sorry for two comments - clicked Enter in the middle)


Add property `article = models.OneToOneField(Article, db_column='id', related_name='article_page'`) in ArticlePages class (never tried to use the same DB column for more than one Django ORM property).


If that works, use it with `.order_by('article_page__page_from')` in your query's line.